# AWS S3 .Net copy object that key contains dots at end

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I use AWSSDK for .Net and my code for copy file is:

```
CopyObjectRequest request = new CopyObjectRequest()
  {
    SourceBucket = _bucketName,
    SourceKey = sourceObjectKey,
    DestinationBucket = _bucketName,
    DestinationKey = targetObjectKey
  };

CopyObjectResponse response = amazonS3Client.CopyObject(request);
```

The code work perfect for normal files but when i tried to copy file with file name like 'mage...' it getting the following error message:

`The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.`

Is there any way to copy object for that type of files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the following C# code to copy files between S3 folders .

```
AmazonS3Config cfg = new AmazonS3Config();
cfg.RegionEndpoint = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUCentral1;//my bucket has this Region
string bucketName = "your bucket";
AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client("your access key", "your secret key", cfg);
S3FileInfo sourceFile = new S3FileInfo(s3Client, bucketName, "FolderNameUniTest179/Test.test.test.pdf");
S3DirectoryInfo targetDir = new S3DirectoryInfo(s3Client, bucketName, "Test");           
sourceFile.CopyTo(targetDir);
S3FileInfo sourceFile2 = new S3FileInfo(s3Client, bucketName, "FolderNameUniTest179/Test...pdf");
sourceFile2.CopyTo(targetDir);
```

I am using amazon AWSSDK.Core and AWSSDK.S3 version 3.1.0.0 for .net 3.5. I hope it can help you.